# Electronic component that is like an LCD version of an LED?

Tags: led, components, lcd, indicator, outdoors

Is there a liquid crystal display version of a light emitting diode? I want a visual indicator that is a small and simple 2 pin device like an LED, but instead of emitting light it just turns black or white, or black and clear like how an LCD screen does.

I want to make a solar electronic compass. Its a magnetometer wired up to a solar panel and then to some kind of indicator that turns on when you point north. LEDs would be perfect for the indicator except they cannot be seen in sunlight, and they drain several milliamps which is a bit much for a solar panel.

LCDs can operate in the microamp range which is perfect, and can also be seen in direct sunlight because they reflect light. This seemed like an ideal fit, but most LCD modules I can find are several inches across which is kind of big for what I had in mind. They also involve a lot of pins and complex interfaces. Also the cheapest LCD modules I could find cost about 2 dollars. All of this is a bit much for a simple on-off visual indicator. LEDs cost like 2 cents each for comparison.

After that I looked into 7 segment displays, but almost all of those that I can find for a reasonable price are LED versions that you would be unable to see in sunlight, and would again draw too much power. They make LCD versions of these too, but they seem to be much more rare and expensive. Again you have a lot of pins and large sizes and higher costs.

All I want is a little plastic dot that can turn black or clear when you run some power to it. Does this exist? This doesn't seem like it should be so hard to find. Does humanity not have little black dot technology? We definitely have little glowing dot technology; you can get LEDs in huge packs for cheap in every color of the rainbow. I guess you could call this a "LCD pixel" or "single-segment LCD display" or something like that.

UPDATE: A few people said I was underestimating the visibility of LEDs and overestimating the visibility of LCDs. I decided to test it just to make sure and took a few photos.

[image: direct sunlight 5:30pm]
Direct sunlight. Left LED is on, right is off for comparison.

[image: shaded from sunlight 5:30pm]
Outside but shaded. Left LED is on, right is off for comparison.

[image: indoors]
Indoors.

I really could see the green LED even in direct sunlight. It was faint, but I could tell that it was on. The LED on the right is completely unpowered for comparison. This LED drew 3.25 milliamps. The LCD I used to compare is a cheap eggtimer I got from walmart for 88 cents.

Judging from the posts here it does not seem like this circuit component exists. The light valve was the closest one and they don't make them small enough to be used for a small indicator.

**Could we get this made?** Based on the large number of views relative to other questions asked on this site it seems like people are interested in a component like this. Is there any chance that writing to some kind of LCD manufacturer could get something like this made?

I know LCDs run on AC power, but I also know factories can build fairly complex circuity right into the plastic somehow. I have seen LEDs that have built in blinker mechanisms, where you just hook them up to a battery and they automatically blink once per second. The blinking circuit is built right into the base of the LED so small you can't even see it. It seems like they could do a similar setup with some sort of h-bridge to invert the power to AC so the LCD would work even just hooked up to regular dc power.

Another possibility was a "Grating light valve" which uses microscopic metal ribbons instead of liquid crystals. As far as I can tell it runs on DC power. It also looks like the patent is just about to expire.

Comment: I think you are being a little bit optimistic on how well you can see LCDs in direct sunlight. The simplest reflective LCD would be a bear to see in bright sun.

Comment: No idea if [these](http://www.lumex.com/content/files/ProductAttachment/LCD-S101M71TR-02.pdf) or [these](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/E%20Ink%20PDFs/SDC722002_DS_12-7-16.pdf) are actually available to be purchased ...

Comment: you can get calculators at the $1 store, 58008 would be a good indicator...

Comment: Maybe check single-element flip dot indicators - yep, electromechanical stuff. the bistable type needs no static power at all!

Comment: for example, https://flipdots.com/en/products-services/status-indicators/

Comment: @rackandboneman Would one of those need to be magnetically shielded to avoid affecting the magnetometer? Otherwise I can imagine the magnetometer detecting north, switching the indicator which interferes with the magnetometer to make it think it's pointing not-north so it switches the indicator...

Comment: I think you're being a bit under-optimistic in how visible LEDs are, how much current you need, and how much current a solar panel can supply.  For example http://store.sundancesolar.com/3v-70ma-solar-cell-10-pack-with-wires/  These aren't exactly tiny at 5cmx5cm, but they'll produce 70mA.  Scaling that down, 2cmx1cm would give you 5.5mA, which is plenty enough to run a red LED and some simple electronics.

Comment: @Andrew Morton hey, it would be an extremely hilarious bug at least. I guess some mu-metal is in orde...

Comment: Oh man, I remember seeing something like this on a dev board a while back and thinking it would be fun to get a bunch of these pixels and make something bigger. It was about the size of an 8 pin DIP. Can't find now. :/ Keep in mind that you can not just apply power to an LCD. It needs an AC signal, but with a modern micro you could use two pins and flip them back and forth across the pixel.

Comment: Try using a diffuse LED instead of a clear one.  They are much easier to see from different angles in the direct sun.  With a clear one, you almost have to be staring straight down it's center from the top.

Answer (score 10):

The closest thing I can think of to what you're describing is an LCD *light valve*. It's a single piece of LCD glass with two electrodes on it. If you've ever used a self-darkening welding helmet, this is what's used to make the window in those. Most of these will probably be bigger than what you have in mind, though.

If you plan on manufacturing this product in quantity, contact an LCD maker. They make custom LCD glass designs all the time -- you could probably get a real "compass" design made, instead of just a single indicator.

Comment: What kind of quantity is "quantity"?

Comment: @immibis Low thousands, maybe? MOQ will depend on the manufacturer.

Answer (score 4):

A better solution for this may be a mechanical thing. This could be a device that works similar to the pixels of a high contrast dot matrix sign where a colored dot is flipped between color or black.

Comment: i was thinking about a neon-painted BB inside a short tube with one end clear, that an electromagnet could push back and forth, or a half-colored disc that rotates. such devices need no power except to update. maybe a magnadoodle slice and coil(s)?

Answer (score 4):

You can buy relatively inexpensive E-Ink modules that have very simple displays (just a few dots / pixels). They provide extremely low power consumption, can be seen under direct sunlight, and interface similarly to LCDs.

Comment: When you say "low power", did you also account for the power consumption of the MCU required to drive such modules?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev an ATtiny will consume 10-12mA running at 8MHz, but can reach about 5µA in low-power sleep (disabling ADC during sleep, etc). If it ran on a ~10% duty cycle and checked every 1/10 sec, your effective power consumption would be ~1-1.5mA while still updating fast enough to be useful to the user. See https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/h2ohno/low-power-attiny for an example.

Comment: @DoktorJ You still have to provide those 10-12mA when the MCU needs them, which calls for a rather big solar panel.

Comment: power draw on a 96x96 eInk display at a 10Hz refresh rate shouldn't exceed 40µA, and decreases if you lower the refresh rate (since it only draws power when redrawing)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev not really? http://www.goldmine-elec-products.com/prodinfo.asp?number=G21358 just a bargain-bin 1.5x3.35 cell, produces up to 60mA @ 6V. Throw in a supercap or small Li-Ion pack to absorb extra juice when it's not needed, and supply when it's not available, and you should be set.

Comment: Two of those cells on either side of [this display](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3335) gives you up to 120mA in a ~3"x4" package. Stick a battery below, and supporting electronics (ATTiny, charging circuitry) below the two solar cells, and you have a nifty little handheld device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61701/discussion-between-doktor-j-and-dmitry-grigoryev).

Comment: @DoktorJ I see no point. The OP wrote that even "several mA" are too much for the solar panel they have. Also note that the solar panel in your link claims to produce 60 mA at 0V, or 0 mA at 6V (and I still belive 60mA claim is bullshit).

Answer (score 2):

If you need low power consumption and ability to see in sunlight, I would recommend using an e-ink display.

The drawbacks are:

1. you will probably need a controller IC,
2. the price.

Answer (score 1):

What you might look for is a single pixel, negative mode, TN 
(twisted nematic) lcd glass. It's black in  powered or unpowered mode, depending on polarizers  used.

Adafruit has one. It looks like it's .75" sq

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but this might fit the bill.

A [flip dot indicator](https://flipdots.com/en/products-services/status-indicators/).

It’s basically a small electromagnetic pulse relay mechanism attached to a fluorescent dot.

It requires considerable current to flip (a couple hundred milliamperes) but it’s just a 2ms pulse.